# Google Analytics Firebase Fragment Tracking

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

My MainActivity is being tracked and I can see the stats on Firebase Google Analytics.

The problem I have is that the Fragments are not being tracked at all.

MainActivity - Tracking correctly

```
    private lateinit var firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)

        val bundle = Bundle()
        bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "my_item_id")

        firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle)

        firebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);

        initToolbar()
        initComponent()
        initData()
        initListeners()

    }
```

Fragments - Not tracking on Google Analytics

```
        private lateinit var firebaseAnalytics: FirebaseAnalytics

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        firebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(mainActivity)

        val params = Bundle()
        params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "screen")
        params.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "UserDashboard")
        firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.VIEW_ITEM, params);

        binding = FragmentUserDashboardBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, false)
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return binding.root
    }
    }
```